# PySpark - GroupBy and aggregation with multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I want to group and aggregate data with several conditions. The dataframe contains a product id, fault codes, date and a fault type. Here, I prepared a sample dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType
from datetime import datetime, date

data  = [("prod_001","fault_01",date(2020, 6, 4),"minor"),
         ("prod_001","fault_03",date(2020, 7, 2),"minor"),
         ("prod_001","fault_09",date(2020, 7, 14),"minor"),
         ("prod_001","fault_01",date(2020, 7, 14),"minor"),
         ("prod_001",None,date(2021, 4, 6),"major"),
         ("prod_001","fault_02",date(2021, 6, 22),"minor"),
         ("prod_001","fault_09",date(2021, 8, 1),"minor"),
         
         ("prod_002","fault_01",date(2020, 6, 13),"minor"),
         ("prod_002","fault_05",date(2020, 7, 11),"minor"),
         ("prod_002",None,date(2020, 8, 1),"major"),
         ("prod_002","fault_01",date(2021, 4, 15),"minor"),
         ("prod_002","fault_02",date(2021, 5, 11),"minor"),
         ("prod_002","fault_03",date(2021, 5, 13),"minor"),
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("product_id",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("fault_code",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("date",DateType(),True), \
    StructField("fault_type", StringType(), True), \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
display(df)
```

In general I would like to do a grouping based on the product_id and a following aggregation of the fault_codes (to lists) for the dates. Some specialties here are the continuing aggregation to a list until the fault_type changes from minor to major. In this case the major tagged row will adopt the last state of the aggregation (see screenshot). Within one product_id the aggregation to a list should then start from new (with the following fault_code which is flagged as minor).

[see target output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdS1.png)

In some other posts I found the following code snippet which I already tried. Unfortunately I didnt make it to the full aggregation with all conditions yet.

```
df.sort("product_id", "date").groupby("product_id", "date").agg(F.collect_list("fault_code"))
```

**Edit:**

Got a little bit closer with `Window.partitionBy()` but still not able to start the `collect_list()` from new once the fault_type changes to major with the following code:

```
df_test = df.sort("product_id", "date").groupby("product_id", "date", "fault_type").agg(F.collect_list("fault_code")).withColumnRenamed('collect_list(fault_code)', 'fault_code_list')

window_function = Window.partitionBy("product_id").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow).orderBy("date")

df_test = df_test.withColumn("new_version_v2", F.collect_list("fault_code_list").over(Window.partitionBy("product_id").orderBy("date"))) \
                 .withColumn("new_version_v2", F.flatten("new_version_v2"))
```

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: How come you drop 1 row for prod_001 (what is the logic, if this is not the mistake)?  Also, why row 3 in the right side dataframe has 2 `fault_09`?

Comment: You're completely right, sorry it was a mistake by myself when creating the example target manually. I corrected the sample table and edited the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit is close. This is not as simple and I only come up with a solution that works but not so neat.

```py
lagw = Window.partitionBy('product_id').orderBy('date')
grpw = Window.partitionBy(['product_id', 'grp']).orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df = (df.withColumn('grp', F.sum(
        (F.lag('fault_type').over(lagw).isNull()
        | (F.lag('fault_type').over(lagw) == 'major')
     ).cast('int')).over(lagw))
     .withColumn('fault_code', F.collect_list('fault_code').over(grpw)))

df.orderBy(['product_id', 'grp']).show()
# +----------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+---+
# |product_id|                              fault_code|      date|fault_type|grp|
# +----------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+---+
# |  prod_001|[fault_01]                              |2020-06-04|     minor|  1|
# |  prod_001|[fault_01, fault_03]                    |2020-07-02|     minor|  1|
# |  prod_001|[fault_01, fault_03, fault_09]          |2020-07-14|     minor|  1|
# |  prod_001|[fault_01, fault_03, fault_09, fault_01]|2020-07-14|     minor|  1|
# |  prod_001|[fault_01, fault_03, fault_09, fault_01]|2021-04-06|     major|  1|
# |  prod_001|[fault_02]                              |2021-06-22|     minor|  2|
# |  prod_001|[fault_02, fault_09]                    |2021-08-01|     minor|  2|
# |  prod_002|[fault_01]                              |2020-06-13|     minor|  1|
# |  prod_002|[fault_01, fault_02]                    |2020-07-11|     minor|  1|
...
```

Explanation:

First I create `grp` column to categorize the consecutive "minor" + following "major". I use `sum` and `lag` to see if the previous row was "major", then I increment, otherwise, I keep the same value as the previous row.

```py
# If cond is True, sum 1, if False, sum 0.
F.sum((cond).cast('int'))
```

```py
df.orderBy(['product_id', 'date']).select('product_id', 'date', 'fault_type', 'grp').show()

+----------+----------+----------+---+
|product_id|      date|fault_type|grp|
+----------+----------+----------+---+
|  prod_001|2020-06-04|     minor|  1|
|  prod_001|2020-07-02|     minor|  1|
|  prod_001|2020-07-14|     minor|  1|
|  prod_001|2020-07-14|     minor|  1|
|  prod_001|2021-04-06|     major|  1|
|  prod_001|2021-06-22|     minor|  2|
|  prod_001|2021-08-01|     minor|  2|
|  prod_002|2020-06-13|     minor|  1|
|  prod_002|2020-07-11|     minor|  1|
...
```

Once this `grp` is generated, I can partition by `product_id` and `grp` to apply `collect_list`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is using Pandas UDF with [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas).

###### Define a "normal" Python function

- Input is a Pandas dataframe and output is another dataframe.
- The dataframe's size doesn't matter

```py
def grp(df):
    df['a'] = 'AAA'
    df = df[df['fault_code'] == 'fault_01']
    return df[['product_id', 'a']]
```

###### Test this function with actual Pandas dataframe

- The only thing to remember is this dataframe is just a subset of your actual dataframe

```py
grp(df.where('product_id == "prod_001"').toPandas())

    product_id  a
0   prod_001    AAA
3   prod_001    AAA
```

###### Apply this function into Spark dataframe with `applyInPandas`

```py
(df
    .groupBy('product_id')
    .applyInPandas(grp, schema)
    .show()
)

                                                                                
+----------+---+
|product_id|  a|
+----------+---+
|  prod_001|AAA|
|  prod_001|AAA|
|  prod_002|AAA|
|  prod_002|AAA|
|  prod_002|AAA|
|  prod_002|AAA|
|  prod_002|AAA|
+----------+---+
```